# Heroku does not find module when local version does

Tags: django, heroku, production

### The problem

So, I have made a website with multiple homemade apps. I now want to deploy this website using Heroku. This doesn't work, however, as I keep getting errors relating to Heroku not being able to find the apps.

When I run the website locally with

```
python manage.py runserver
```

everything behaves as expected.

When I, however, try to deploy this website using Heroku I get an error (stack trace provided underneath).

### Project structure

```
towima
|   .gitignore
|   Procfile
|   README.md
|   requirements.txt
|   runtime.txt
|   tree.txt
|   
+---media_cdn
|   |   .DS_Store
|   |   
|   \---products
|                       
\---towima
    |   .DS_Store
    |   db.sqlite3
    |   manage.py
    |   pharma_locations.json
    |   __init__.py
    |   
    +---accounts
    |   |   admin.py
    |   |   apps.py
    |   |   forms.py
    |   |   models.py
    |   |   tests.py
    |   |   urls.py
    |   |   views.py
    |   |   __init__.py
    |   |   
    |   +---migrations
    +---api
    |   |   admin.py
    |   |   apps.py
    |   |   models.py
    |   |   serializers.py
    |   |   tests.py
    |   |   urls.py
    |   |   views.py
    |   |   __init__.py
    |   |   
    |   +---migrations
    |           
    +---orders
    |   |   admin.py
    |   |   apps.py
    |   |   forms.py
    |   |   models.py
    |   |   tests.py
    |   |   urls.py
    |   |   views.py
    |   |   __init__.py
    |   |   
    |   +---migrations
    |           
    +---pharmacies
    |   |   admin.py
    |   |   apps.py
    |   |   forms.py
    |   |   models.py
    |   |   tests.py
    |   |   urls.py
    |   |   views.py
    |   |   __init__.py
    |   |   
    |   +---migrations
    |           
    +---products
    |   |   admin.py
    |   |   apps.py
    |   |   forms.py
    |   |   models.py
    |   |   tests.py
    |   |   urls.py
    |   |   views.py
    |   |   __init__.py
    |   |   
    |   +---migrations
    |           
    +---static
    |               
    +---staticfiles
    +---templates
    |           
    \---towima
        |   admin.py
        |   models.py
        |   settings.py
        |   urls.py
        |   views.py
        |   wsgi.py
        |   __init__.py
```

### My Procfile

```
web: gunicorn towima.towima.wsgi --log-file -
```

### My wsgi.py file

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'towima.towima.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

previously, the os.environ.setdefault contained 'towima.settings' but I changed it to what it is now because otherwise, it would not locate the correct folder.

### The relevant section of the settings.py file

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'accounts',         # The account app
    'towima',           # Our own app
    'products',         #products App
    'pharmacies',       #Pharmacy App
    'orders',           #Orders App
    'rest_framework',
    'crispy_forms',
    'api',
]
```

The problem is here I think. When I run the website locally it finds all the apps, but when I try it in Heroku I get the error that there is no module named accounts. When I comment accounts out to see what happens, it gave me the error that there is no module named products. This leads me to believe it looks in the wrong folder because there is no error for the towima module. When I change the app name from `'accounts'` to `'towima.accounts'`, it crashed locally and also does not work on Heroku.

### The stacktrace

```
2019-02-09T19:37:45.956108+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn towima.towima.wsgi --log-file -`
2019-02-09T19:37:47.980579+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-02-09 19:37:47 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
2019-02-09T19:37:47.981190+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-02-09 19:37:47 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:45237 (4)
2019-02-09T19:37:47.981279+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-02-09 19:37:47 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2019-02-09T19:37:47.986079+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-02-09 19:37:47 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2019-02-09T19:37:48.007337+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-02-09 19:37:48 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
2019-02-09T19:37:48.242699+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-02-09 19:37:48 +0000] [11] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2019-02-09T19:37:48.242725+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-02-09T19:37:48.242727+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2019-02-09T19:37:48.242729+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2019-02-09T19:37:48.242730+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
2019-02-09T19:37:48.242732+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2019-02-09T19:37:48.242733+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
2019-02-09T19:37:48.242735+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2019-02-09T19:37:48.242737+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2019-02-09T19:37:48.242738+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2019-02-09T19:37:48.242740+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
2019-02-09T19:37:48.242741+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2019-02-09T19:37:48.242743+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
2019-02-09T19:37:48.242744+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2019-02-09T19:37:48.242746+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
2019-02-09T19:37:48.242747+00:00 app[web.1]: __import__(module)
2019-02-09T19:37:48.242749+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/towima/towima/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
2019-02-09T19:37:48.242750+00:00 app[web.1]: application = get_wsgi_application()
2019-02-09T19:37:48.242751+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2019-02-09T19:37:48.242753+00:00 app[web.1]: django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2019-02-09T19:37:48.242754+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
2019-02-09T19:37:48.242756+00:00 app[web.1]: apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
2019-02-09T19:37:48.242757+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 89, in populate
2019-02-09T19:37:48.242759+00:00 app[web.1]: app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
2019-02-09T19:37:48.242760+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
2019-02-09T19:37:48.242761+00:00 app[web.1]: module = import_module(entry)
2019-02-09T19:37:48.242763+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2019-02-09T19:37:48.242764+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2019-02-09T19:37:48.242766+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'accounts'
2019-02-09T19:37:48.242921+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-02-09 19:37:48 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
2019-02-09T19:37:48.266614+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-02-09 19:37:48 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2019-02-09T19:37:48.266619+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-02-09T19:37:48.266621+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2019-02-09T19:37:48.266623+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2019-02-09T19:37:48.266625+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
2019-02-09T19:37:48.266627+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2019-02-09T19:37:48.266628+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
2019-02-09T19:37:48.266630+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2019-02-09T19:37:48.266632+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2019-02-09T19:37:48.266634+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2019-02-09T19:37:48.266635+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
2019-02-09T19:37:48.266637+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2019-02-09T19:37:48.266639+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
2019-02-09T19:37:48.266640+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2019-02-09T19:37:48.266642+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
2019-02-09T19:37:48.266644+00:00 app[web.1]: __import__(module)
2019-02-09T19:37:48.266646+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/towima/towima/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
2019-02-09T19:37:48.266648+00:00 app[web.1]: application = get_wsgi_application()
2019-02-09T19:37:48.266649+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2019-02-09T19:37:48.266651+00:00 app[web.1]: django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2019-02-09T19:37:48.266653+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
2019-02-09T19:37:48.266654+00:00 app[web.1]: apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
2019-02-09T19:37:48.266656+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 89, in populate
2019-02-09T19:37:48.266657+00:00 app[web.1]: app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
2019-02-09T19:37:48.266659+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
2019-02-09T19:37:48.266661+00:00 app[web.1]: module = import_module(entry)
2019-02-09T19:37:48.266662+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2019-02-09T19:37:48.266664+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2019-02-09T19:37:48.266666+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'accounts'
2019-02-09T19:37:48.266819+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-02-09 19:37:48 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2019-02-09T19:37:48.401363+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-02-09 19:37:48 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2019-02-09T19:37:48.401446+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-02-09 19:37:48 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2019-02-09T19:37:48.490323+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-02-09T19:37:48.471230+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
```

If someone could help me out, I would be so grateful because I am losing my mind here. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you successfully deploy the plain `django-admin startproject mysite` ?

Comment: what do you mean by this? I started my project like this if that is the question.

Comment: Yes but could you deploy a minimial example without errors?

Comment: Maybe deploy this [minimal example first](https://github.com/heroku/python-getting-started) and than add parts of your app on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

Rename the topfolder to something else.

And then change

```
web: gunicorn towima.towima.wsgi --log-file -
```

to

```
web: gunicorn towima.wsgi --log-file -
```

and

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'towima.towima.settings')
```

to

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'towima.settings')
```

Comment: I don't believe it can be due to a missing Pipfile, as the docs specify that any of the possibilities (including requirements.txt which i have) should be in the project.